# SQL prepared statement gems for Ruby 1.9/2.0

Tags: sql, ruby, rubygems, prepared-statement

Is there a specific gem for using prepared statements for a SQL database within ruby? I've used the mysql2 gem in the past, but from its hard to build native extension and its lack of prepared statements I do not think it is the right gem for me.

I am looking for suggestions for a new database to switch to in which the ruby gem is easier to build without the hassle, or a gem which supports prepared statements (or both!).

The purpose for this would be such projects which I would need to expose a protocol to the internet and it would check data which users can potentially tamper with against a database. For example a chat server which stores static registered channels within the database.

If there are no gems that have prepared statements or built in functionality to prevent attacks from unsanitized input, what would be the best way to attempt to sanitize user input before using it with any database.

Also to note that this if for ruby itself and not rails.

Thank you for any comments or answers that can lead to a solution to these questions.

Comment: There is an `escape` method in mysql2 but that's smells as musty as PHP from 1999. Can you switch to PostgreSQL? The pg gem supports proper prepared statements and placeholders.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes I can switch databases as stated in my question. Is it possible for you to show an example code of what this may look like, or even a link to the development page of the postgresql gem?

Comment: You can start here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/frames

Comment: @muistooshort Alright thank you. I will check it out.